# font change for chapter, section, subsection titles

Tags: titlesec

So, i am struggling to change the font for title/section/subsection in latex.

Here is my code :

```
% !TEX TS?program = pdflatexmk

\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathpazo}

%changing font of section/chapter title
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newfontfamily\headingfont{Papyrus}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\LARGE\headingfont}
\titleformat{\section}{\LARGE\headingfont}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\Large\headingfont}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\large\headingfont}



\title{my report}
\author{user name}
\date


\linespread{1.5}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\maketitle
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tableofcontents
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{introduction}
text : intro
\section{first section}
text :  section
\subsection{this subsection}
text :section
\subsubsection{this and that subsection}
text :subsub
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

And this is the output: 
[image]
The font is only implemented in the `chapter` and `subsection`. Not for others. 
And also the numbering is lost. For example, without `titlesec`and `fontspec` this is what it looks like. The chapter and subsection numbering is lost with that. 
I cant find the bug. (also kind of annoying to use fontspec as it could not find the default latex font, so had to copy paste the `otf` file in the working directory)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

[image: sample]

Here’s modified code

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\myheadingfont{Papyrus}

% changing font of section/chapter title

\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{(\arabic{chapter})\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\LARGE\myheadingfont}{\chaptertitlename~\thechapter.}{.4em}{\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{\section}{\LARGE\myheadingfont}{Section~\thesection.}{.2em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\Large\myheadingfont}{subsection~\thesubsection:}{.2em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\large\myheadingfont}{\S~\thesubsubsection~}{.2em}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{introduction}
text : intro
\section{first section}
text : section
\subsection{this subsection}
text : subsection
\subsubsection{this and that subsection}
text : subsub

\end{document}
```

`\titleformat` takes five non-optional parameters `\titleformat{which}[shape]{format}{label}{hsep}{before-code}[after-code]` (see http://ctan.altspu.ru/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf). When you wish to change just format, then you would probably like its *-variant `\titleformat*{which}{format}`

For chapter, you may wish to place its text on other line, in such case use `\titleformat{\chapter}[display]` not `[hang]`

`\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` is that thing which adds numbering to “subsub”s too